# How to release late bound COM objects?

Tags: c#, .net, com, release, late-binding

I guess I do have to release also late bound COM objects.
But how is this done directly?

In my situation I use the following code from C# to get the focused point from Google Earth (simplified):

```
Type oClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("GoogleEarth.ApplicationGE");
object oGE = Activator.CreateInstance(oClassType);
object oCamera = oGE.GetType().InvokeMember("GetCamera", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oGE, new object[] { 0 });
double dFocusLatitude = (double)oCamera.GetType().InvokeMember("FocusPointLatitude", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oCamera, null);
double dFocusLongitude = (double)oCamera.GetType().InvokeMember("FocusPointLongitude", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oCamera, null);
```

So how to I release the camera and Google Earth objects in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)

e.g.

```
if(Marshal.IsComObject(oGE)==true)
{
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oGE);
}
```